# ROS2 prerelease website

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a prerelease website for ROS2 similar to the [ROS1 prerelease website](http://prerelease.ros.org/)? Are you planning to run one in case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300248/ros2-prerelease-website/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not currently an equivalent. I expect in the future that we will be able to extend that site to support both ROS 1 and ROS 2 distros in the future. We do not yet have the job types fully integrated for deploying it on ROS 2 versions of the distro yet.

Any interest or contributions would be appreciated and could likely make this happen sooner.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-10**:
We do have the logic for prerelease jobs for ROS 2. They are basically devel jobs run locally. Only the prerelease site doesn't support ROS 2 atm. Since the website only generates a command you need to run locally you can "construct" that manually.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-10**:
You will need a custom `ROSDISTRO_INDEX_URL` mentioned in https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Releasing-a-ROS-2-package-with-bloom#differences-from-ros-1-bloom as well as the `ros_buildfarm` package from this branch: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/548